# round microseconds in datetime

Tags: python, datetime, rounding

I have some datetime objects and I want to approximate the object by removing the microseconds and increment the second if the microseconds are > 500000, like in this way:

`2021-10-11 09:50:00.025245`  --->  `2021-10-03 09:50:00`

`2021-10-11 09:50:00.725245`  --->  `2021-10-03 09:50:01`

This is the code I wrote, that works fine, but I wold like to know if is there a more efficient / elegan way to achive this result.

```
def rounded_datetime(current_datetime):
    rounded_microseconds = round(current_datetime.microsecond / 1000000)
    new_seconds = current_datetime.second + rounded_microseconds
    new_minutes = current_datetime.minute if new_seconds < 60 else current_datetime.minute + 1
    new_hours = current_datetime.hour if new_minutes < 60 else current_datetime.hour + 1
    new_day = current_datetime.day if current_datetime.hour < 24 else current_datetime.day + 1
    return current_datetime.replace(microsecond=0, second=new_seconds if new_seconds < 60 else 0,
                                    minute=new_minutes if new_minutes < 60 else 0,
                                    hour=new_hours if new_hours < 24 else 0, day=new_day)
```

Comment: An easier approach would be to get microsencond, replace microsecond with 0 and then add `timedelta(seconds=1)` if microsecond >= 500000

Answer (score 2):

check the microsecond attribute and add a timedelta of one second if it is greater 500000:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# round_to_sec takes a datetime object and returns a new datetime object
#     rounded to the nearest second
def round_to_sec(dt: datetime):
    if dt.microsecond>=500000:
        return (dt.replace(microsecond=0)+timedelta(seconds=1))
    return dt.replace(microsecond=0)

for s in "2021-10-11 09:50:00.025245", "2021-10-11 09:50:00.725245":
    print(s, "->", round_to_sec(datetime.fromisoformat(s)))

# 2021-10-11 09:50:00.025245 -> 2021-10-11 09:50:00
# 2021-10-11 09:50:00.725245 -> 2021-10-11 09:50:01
```

Comment: Named lambdas aren't pythonic and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) discourages their usage.

Comment: @accdias: thanks for the hint, wasn't aware of "*the name of the resulting function object is specifically 'f' instead of the generic '<lambda>'. This is more useful for tracebacks and string representations in general.*"

Comment: No worries. I guess it is just me always being picky about PEP8. :-)